# How do I replace a string in an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have some code where I have an array with the days of the week. I don't know how to replace `"Thursday"` with `"Tuesday"`. I've tried researching with no luck... :/
Any help is appreciated.

```
daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

Comment: switch thursday and tuesday or only replace thursday by tuesday ?

Comment: @SPSP I need to do it in another line of code. EG: daysOfWeek.append[ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, name in enumerate(daysOfWeek):
    if name == "Thursday":
        daysOfWeek[i] = "Tuesday"
```

this should work

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you!

Comment: @LadyPenelope You should accept

Comment: @JoeIddon Thanks, I'm new to Stackoverflow but finally figured out how to accept!

Answer (score 0):

`daysOfWeek = [day.replace('Thursday', 'Tuesday') for day in daysOfWeek]`

This is Python 3 Implementation.
For more [info](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a variable to store the to be replaced value.

Example:
    
    `abc=days[x]
    day[x]=day[y]
    day[y]=abc`

Using append is easier and uses less memory since you do not need an extra variable. This is just an alternative method.
Note:
x is value to be replaced
y is the the value doing the replacing until it becomes x
abc is a variable.

Hope it helps!
TheTRCG
Questions:
thetrcg@gmail.com